# Multiplying two lists in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I am currently working with prolog and want to multiply two lists together but in a certian way. For example:

```
[1,2,3] and [4,5,6] are my two lists.
```

I want to preform the following actions:

```
(1*4)+(2*5)+(3*6) = 32
```

Such that the first element of each list is multiplied to each other then added with the second elements multiplied together etc.

Is this possible to go in Prolog?

I know in other languages you can do a recursive function with takes the head of the list and the tail (the rest of the entries). This allows for a simple multiplication but I do not think that is possible in prolog?

Comment: Have you read any prolog tutorials or books? Why would you think that recursive list processing may not be possible in prolog? It's a very common operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using built-ins:

```
mult(X, Y, Z) :- Z is X * Y.

sum_prod(A, B, SumProd) :-
    maplist(mult, A, B, Prods),
    sumlist(Prods, SumProd).   % In GNU Prolog this is sum_list
```

Using simple recursion:

```
sum_prod([A|As], [B|Bs], SumProd) :-
    sum_prod(As, Bs, SP),
    SumProd is SP + A*B.
sum_prod([], [], 0).
```

Using tail recursion:

```
sum_prod(A, B, SumProd) :-
    sum_prod(A, B, 0, SumProd).
sum_prod([A|As], [B|Bs], Acc, SumProd) :-
    Acc1 is Acc + A*B,
    sum_prod(As, Bs, Acc1, SumProd).
sum_prod([], [], Acc, Acc).
```

Comment: I've been reading a lot of your answers Lurker, really helping me learn Prolog, thank you

Answer (score 2):

If all items of your lists are integers and your Prolog implementation offers [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd), you can simply use the 
clpfd built-in predicate [`scalar_product/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html#scalar_product/4), like this:

```
?- scalar_product([1,2,3],[4,5,6],#=,Product).
Product = 32.
```

---

**Edit:** 
You may also be interested in the related question "[Prolog: Multiplying 2 lists with 1 of them not instantiated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29424471/prolog-multiplying-2-lists-with-1-of-them-not-instantiated)", particularly in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29426291/4609915).

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative to 'hand coded' loops, using library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)) and [nth1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nth1/3)/3:

```
sum_prod(A,B,S) :-
    aggregate(sum(M), I^X^Y^(nth1(I,A,X), nth1(I,B,Y), M is X*Y), S).
```