# Appending in Prolog and recursion

Tags: recursion, prolog

I am currently creating a function in Prolog which appends a number generated by another function that is tested and works. Here is my function:

```
append([], Y, Y).
append([H|X], Y, [H|Z]) :- append(X, Y, Z).

function(A,[B|Bs],X):-
   oldNumber(A,B,Hold),
   append([Hold],function(A,Bs,X)).
```

So I have an append function which works correctly. Then I have function which is a recursive function which appends the different numbers. oldNumber outputs a number in Hold and then I put Hold into the first slot in append.

Here is an example that is not working correctly:

```
 function([1.; -1.; 1.; -1.], [[0.; -1.; 1.; -1.], [-1.; 0.; -1.; 1.], [1.; -1.; 0.; -1][-1.; 1.; -1.; 0.]], X).
 Id be looking for [3.; -3.; 3.; -3.]
```

It returns false but I can not figure out why. Any ideas?

Comment: `append` is defined as `append/3` (three arguments) but is used as `append/2` in `function`

Comment: and if you plan on calling `function` recursively, you need a `function(A,[],A)` or something like that

Comment: I really can't figure out what is supposed to *do* `function`

Comment: So this is what I meant to do. OldNumber will return a number such as 1 and put it in a list in append. This will then be appended with the tail of B. But I see I only put in two arguments for append. What would the third one be if Im just trying to append [1] with tail of B?

Comment: edit your code showing what is your expected result for the example

Comment: @user081608: You are trying to describe your problem in terms of usual imperative programming and that won't help us to understand it for solving it in prolog. Try to describe it in terms of relationships between the variables that each predicate describes

Comment: @Ankur can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: @user081608: For example you mentioned that the `function returns` and in your code also you are calling it like a function `append([Hold],function(A,Bs,X))`, whereas the word function is a predicate in your code. You can also try to give a example input/ouput to describe the problem without referring to any code as that would make it more clear

Comment: I added an example of something I know I should be getting. Also, I have just started Prolog so I am just getting used to it. I understand what you say in your comment.

Comment: As @Ankur is indicating, prolog doesn't have *functions*, it has *predicates*. A *predicate* does not return a value that you use as an argument in another expression. A *predicate* is a query on a relation which will either succeed or fail. Generally speaking, if the query succeeds, prolog will continue to the next query. If it fails, it will backtrack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in the example given, `oldNumber` does what is asked for in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207594/multiplying-two-lists-in-prolog).

If this is the case, you should need the following code:

```
function(_,[],[]).
function(A,[B|Bs],[X|Xs]):-
   net(A,B,X),
   function(A,Bs,Xs).

net([],_,0).
net(_,[],0).
net([I|Is], [W|Ws], Sum) :-
    net(Is, Ws, Acc),
    Sum is Acc + I * W.
```

Let me explain it to you:

You are making a list of `Xs`, in which each `X` is applying `oldNumber` and then going to the next one...

So you specify `function(A,[B|Bs],[X|Xs])` because you will set `X` and then work the rest of the list (`Xs`).

You get this `X` by using `oldNumber(A,B,X)`, which binds the two `X`.

And then you take care of the rest of the list (`Xs`) with a recursive use of `function(A,Bs,Xs)`.

Now you just take care of the *base case*, when the list of `Bs` gets empty, `function(A,[],[])`.

---

Now an example:

```
function([1,2,3],[[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]],X).
X = [6, 12, 18] .
```

Comment: Very Interesting. Im just confused why you didnt append anything?

Comment: It's going through the list by calling it recursively.

Comment: Okay I see what your saying I think. I just implemented your example and I got the same false as before. Any thoughts? Also function is underlined when I use it for recursion for some reason.

Comment: I tested it, make sure you wrote everything right. Was the thing asked in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207594/multiplying-two-lists-in-prolog) what `oldNumber` does?

Comment: Yup It provides a single value such as 1.

Comment: In that case it should work. Check that you are writing everything right. I have edited the answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49112/discussion-between-chamini2-and-user081608)