# Prolog: Multiplying 2 lists with 1 of them not instantiated?

Tags: recursion, prolog, dot-product

I am trying to write a rule that can return the sum of the product of each element from two lists (same length).

Here is what I have right now:

```
sum(0, _, []).
sum(Result, [H1|T1], [H2|T2]) :- 
    sum(Remaining,T1, T2),
    Remaining is Result - (H1*H2).
```

It won't work when one of the list is not instantiated. What changes I need to make in order to make the following possible?

```
sum([1,2],X,3).
X = [3,0].
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think `X = [1,1]` is also a correct answer in your example. Do you want it to yield all answers? Or do you have some other constraint? Based upon the example, I assume you are dealing with only non-negative integers? You didn't say. Is this an assignment? Are you allowed to use the CLPFD library? That would be the natural way to handle this problem.

Comment: @lurker Yes it should yield all answers with non-neative integer input. It is from an assignment, therefore I can't use any libraries. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are calculating is commonly referred to as a [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) (also known as scalar product or inner product).

You write you are not allowed to use libraries. That surely refers to **external** libraries---not to the *standard library* that is part of SWI Prolog, right?

The following predicate `list_list_dotProduct/3` roughly corresponds to the code you implemented. It uses finite domain constraints `(#>=)/2` and `(#=)/2` to allow for non-unidirectional integer arithmetic:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

list_list_dotProduct([],[],0).
list_list_dotProduct([X|Xs],[Y|Ys],Sum) :-
    X   #>= 0,
    Y   #>= 0,
    Sum #=  X*Y + Sum0,
    list_list_dotProduct(Xs,Ys,Sum0).
```

Consider the following query:

```
?- list_list_dotProduct([1,2],Xs,3), label(Xs).
Xs = [1, 1] ;
Xs = [3, 0].
```

---

As an added bonus, here's an *alternative implementation* that is based on the predefined predicates `same_length/2`, `ins/2`, and `scalar_product/4`:

```
list_list_dotProduct(Xs,Ys,Prod) :-
    same_length(Xs,Ys),
    Xs ins 0..sup,
    Ys ins 0..sup,
    scalar_product(Xs,Ys,#=,Prod).
```

Comment: Great answer. There has been a deluge of variations of this question in the past week or so. Still not very clear whether whoever gave this exercise explicitly forbid the use of a library like clp(fd), or if the students misunderstood. It is also a bit sad that the instructor of the class left the students so unprepared.

Comment: You would be amazed how badly Prolog is taught _in some_ higher education institutions. So badly that it would be better to say "There is a language called Prolog, google it" and leave it there. Teaching something badly is only damaging.

Comment: Great solution, +1! Beware though that `scalar_product/4` requires that its first argument be ground, so the second version of `list_list_dotProduct/3` will not work when it is the *first* argument that contains variables, as for example in: `?- list_list_dotProduct([X,Y], [1,2], Prod).`. Your initial version works as expected in such cases as well. I also highly recommend CLP(FD) constraints for this kind of problems. People who require that CLP(FD) not be used in such cases are in my view requiring "the use of Prolog without using Prolog".